# Laravel 5.2: create image thumbnails in using intervention

Tags: php, laravel-5, intervention

I am trying to create image thumbnails using intervention here is my controller

```
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            $image = $request->file('image');
            $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            Image::make($image)->resize(600, 390)->save(public_path('images/blog/' . $filename));
            $image->fit(240, 157)->save(public_path('images/blog/' . $filename . '-thumbs.jpg'));
            $add->image = $filename;
        }
```

Got

> Method fit does not exist.

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Like the error says. It's saying that: $image->fit(240, 157)->save(public_path('images/blog/' . $filename . '-thumbs.jpg')); does not exist

Comment: @Mitch yes I saw that, I hit the `intervention` documentation and I got this from there `http://image.intervention.io/api/fit` so how come does not exist. My question is what I did wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update this line:

```
Image::make($image)->resize(600, 390)->save(public_path('images/blog/' . $filename));
```

to

```
$image = Image::make($image)->resize(600, 390)->save(public_path('images/blog/' . $filename));
```

because `fit` is a method of `InterventionImage` object.